# Procedure to update with Cursor got partial update result

Tags: plsql

I don't know why my code only updated 2 out of 8 rows selected from cursor. The procedure was supposed to update all the product cost that are lower than the new calculated cost, to the new calculated cost. But it only updated 2 rows. (Each Product has many parts, AND each part can be used in multiple products.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_Update_Curr_Cost

AS
        CURSOR C_Prod_Cost IS 
            SELECT pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost, SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost)
            FROM Product pd, Product_Part pp, Part pa
            WHERE pd.Product_ID = pp.Product_ID AND
                  pp.Part_ID = pa.Part_ID
            GROUP BY pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost
            HAVING SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost) > Product_Cost
            ORDER BY pd.Product_ID;        
        V_Product_ID    NUMBER(5,0);
        V_Prod_Cost     NUMBER(6,2);
        V_Cur_Prod_Cost NUMBER(6,2);
BEGIN
        OPEN C_Prod_Cost;
        LOOP
        FETCH C_Prod_Cost INTO V_Product_ID, V_Prod_Cost, V_Cur_Prod_Cost;
        EXIT WHEN C_Prod_Cost%NOTFOUND;           
            UPDATE Product
            SET Product_Cost = V_Cur_Prod_Cost
            WHERE Product_ID = V_Product_ID;    
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'All product cost are up to date. No change needed.');
    WHEN invalid_cursor THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20998, 'Cursor error has occured. Contact techical support');
    WHEN others THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20997, 'An undetermined error has occured. Contact techical support');
END PR_Update_Curr_Cost;
```

Before the update:

Product_ID   Product_Cost New Calculated Production Cost

---

```
       2          .62                          .7875
       3            1                        3.31625
       4          3.4                       12.94125
       5          .64                           1.12
       7         7.46                      12.466125
       8         1.32                       6.444375
       9          .27                        2.35375
      10          .44                         2.5375
```

8 rows selected.

After the update:

Product_ID   Product_Cost New Calculated Production Cost

---

```
       3            1                        3.31625
       4          3.4                       12.94125
       5          .64                           1.12
       8         1.32                       6.444375
       9          .27                        2.35375
      10          .44                         2.5375
```

6 rows selected.

LOAD TABLE:

```
Drop Table Product_Part;
Drop Table Product;
Drop Table Part;

Create Table Product
(
    Product_ID   Number(5,0)   Constraint PK_Pr_PrID primary key
                               Constraint NN_Pr_PrID not null,
    Product_Name Varchar2(50)  Constraint NN_Pr_PrName not null,
    Product_Cost Number(6,2)   Default '0'
                               Constraint NN_Pr_PrCost not null
                               Constraint CK_Pr_PrCost
                                    Check (Product_Cost >= 0)
);

Create Table Part
(
    Part_ID      Number(4,0)   Constraint PK_Pa_PaID primary key
                               Constraint NN_Pa_PaID not null,
    Part_Name    Varchar2(40)  Constraint NN_Pa_PaName not null,
    Current_Cost Number(5,2)   Default '0'
                               Constraint NN_Pa_CurCost not null
                               Constraint CK_Pa_CurCost
                                     Check (Current_Cost >=0)
);

Create Table Product_Part
(
    Product_ID   Number(5,0)  Constraint FK_PP_PrID_Pr_PrID
                                     References Product (Product_ID)
                              Constraint NN_PP_PrID not null,                                                
    Part_ID  Number(4,0)      Constraint FK_PP_PaID_Pa_PaID
                                     References Part (Part_ID)
                              Constraint NN_PP_PaID not null,                                               
    Qty_Needed   Number(6,2)  Default '1'
                              Constraint NN_PP_QtyNeeded not null,                             
            Constraint PK_PP primary key (Product_ID, Part_ID)            
);

-- Insert Into Product

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (1,'Coffee (Fair Trade)', 0.27);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (10, 'Chocolate Sundae', 0.44);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (2,'Coke (591 ml)', 0.62);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (8,'Hamburger Deluxe',1.32);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (3,'Bayou Seafood Gumbo (small)',1.00);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (4,'Hot Louisiana Crab Dip',3.40);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (6,'Fettuccine Alfredo', 4.01);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (7,'Roasted Salmon with Lemon Thyme Crust', 7.46);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (5,'Caesar Salad (starter size)', 0.64);

Insert Into Product
    (Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost)
Values
    (9,'Oven Fried Potatoes', 0.27);

-- Insert Into Part

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (35, 'Potatoes', 0.04);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (10, 'Oil', 0.13);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (22, 'Salmon Steak (4 oz)', 3.28);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (11, 'Ketchup', 0.11);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (34, 'Pepper', 0.25);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (12, 'White Sugar', 0.08);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (20, 'Fresh Tiger Prawns', 0.26);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (21, 'Fettuccine', 0.56);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (13, 'Cream', 0.25);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (14, 'Coke (575 ml)', 0.45);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (17, 'Eggs', 0.11);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (18, 'Romaine Lettuce', 1.25);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (19, 'Vinegar', 0.18);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (23, 'Mustard', 0.18);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (24, 'French Fries', 0.07);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (25, 'Ice Cream', 0.35);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (36, 'Diced Organic Tomatoes', 0.17);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (37, 'Relish', 0.07);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (38, 'Almonds', 0.05);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (26, 'Crushed Almonds', 0.21);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (28, 'Taragon', 2.24);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (27, 'Chocolate Sauce', 0.34);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (29, 'Coffee (Organic Fair Trade)', 0.22);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (30, 'Hamburger', 0.93);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (15, 'Chicken Breast Filet', 0.48);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (16, 'Alaskan King Crab Meat', 3.45);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (31, 'Salt', 0.21);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (32, 'Tea', 0.80);

Insert Into Part
    (Part_ID, Part_Name, Current_Cost)
Values
    (33, 'Bun', 0.12);

-- Insert Into Product_Part

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (4, 16, 2.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (2, 14, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (3, 13, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (3, 34, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (3, 15, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (3, 20, 4.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (1, 13, 0.10);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (1, 12, 0.10);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (1, 29, 0.40);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 30, 3.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (10, 26, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (10, 25, 3.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (9, 35, 4.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 34, 0.05);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 12, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 23, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 35, 2.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 36, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 31, 0.10);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (7, 22, 2.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 33, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (9, 10, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (5, 10, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (10, 27, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (5, 19, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (6, 13, 2.25);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 24, 3.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 36, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 37, 0.25);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (6, 17, 2.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 10, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (5, 36, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 11, 2.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (5, 18, 0.20);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (4, 17, 2.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (4, 34, 0.10);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (4, 13, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (6, 21, 1.00);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (10, 38, 2.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (8, 23, 0.50);

Insert Into Product_Part
    (Product_ID, Part_ID, Qty_Needed)
Values
    (9, 28, 0.50);
```

Comment: you need to use the aggregate SUM function.

Comment: Hi, I just updated more info: each Product has many parts, AND each part can be used in multiple products. I should use the aggregate SUM function still?

Comment: Create the tables, enter some data and then start playing with the data. Create a query on the product table only, then join to product_part and part to figure out what parts are used for a product. Once you have verified that query, modify it to use aggregate function SUM. When stuck, debug your code. If you are blocked completely, post a question with [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of what you tried so far. Attachments/screenshots are discouraged - no one likes to type, including people helping others.

Comment: @koenlostrie Thank you so much for your advice. I tried all the steps you suggested and came up with this solution. Can you please have a look to see why it got a partial update even though there was no error?

Comment: Happy to if ... you provide ddl scripts ( create table scripts ) and dml scripts (script to insert the data) for all 3 tables so I can run a test. I prefer not posting untested code. Pls post as scripts not as screenshots.

Comment: @KoenLostrie Thank you for your reply. I just added create and insert script, pls have a look  ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me. I ran the ddl/dml script to create the objects, then checked what rows would be updated by the procedure by running the query from the cursor:

```
SELECT pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost, SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost)
  FROM Product pd, Product_Part pp, Part pa
 WHERE pd.Product_ID = pp.Product_ID AND
       pp.Part_ID = pa.Part_ID
 GROUP BY pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost
       HAVING SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost) > Product_Cost
 ORDER BY pd.Product_ID;   

3   1       1.895
4   3.4     7.395
8   1.32    3.6825
9   0.27    1.345
10  0.44    1.45
```

Then I ran the procedure to update the rows:

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR C_Prod_Cost IS 
            SELECT pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost, SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost)
            FROM Product pd, Product_Part pp, Part pa
            WHERE pd.Product_ID = pp.Product_ID AND
                  pp.Part_ID = pa.Part_ID
            GROUP BY pd.Product_ID, Product_Cost
            HAVING SUM(Qty_Needed*Current_Cost) > Product_Cost
            ORDER BY pd.Product_ID;        
        V_Product_ID    NUMBER(5,0);
        V_Prod_Cost     NUMBER(6,2);
        V_Cur_Prod_Cost NUMBER(6,2);
BEGIN
        OPEN C_Prod_Cost;
        LOOP
        FETCH C_Prod_Cost INTO V_Product_ID, V_Prod_Cost, V_Cur_Prod_Cost;
        EXIT WHEN C_Prod_Cost%NOTFOUND;           
            UPDATE Product
            SET Product_Cost = V_Cur_Prod_Cost
            WHERE Product_ID = V_Product_ID;    
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20999, 'All product cost are up to date. No change needed.');
    WHEN invalid_cursor THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20998, 'Cursor error has occured. Contact techical support');
    WHEN others THEN
        CLOSE C_Prod_Cost;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20997, 'An undetermined error has occured. Contact techical support');
END;
/
```

and checked the original query. The result was

```
8   3.68    3.6825
```

So ... seems that due to a rounding issue one record was not updated to the correct value but other than that, the procedure updated all the rows that needed updating. Why are you saying it doesn't work ? How did you come to that conclusion ?

Comment: Hmm weird. My result is different from yours: 

Procedure PR_UPDATE_CURR_COST compiled


PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_COST SUM(QTY_NEEDED*CURRENT_COST)
---------- ------------ ----------------------------
         3            1                        1.895
         4          3.4                        7.395
         8         1.32                       3.6825
         9          .27                        1.345
        10          .44                         1.45

Comment: Ohhh!! I realized that I forgot to execute the procedure! Problem solved. Thank you so much for guiding me from the beginning. This is the first time I solved a problem :D :D